# Barcode fonts not working in LibHaru PDF lib

Tags: fonts, barcode, libharu

I am trying to use barcode font(ADVC128C.TTF) in libharu but it is not printing(`throwing exception - Unsupported ttf format`). I have used `HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile()` to load font file.
 How do we print the barcode by using LibHaru pdf library? Could you please help me into this?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kadam.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an other Barcode font (code128.ttf) It was missing `cvt` and `fpgm` which are required tags for libharu.
I set the `HPDF_REQUIRED_TAGS_COUNT` down by 2 and eliminated those `REQUIRED_TAGS` . Both are found in `hpdf_fontdef_tt.c`.

This worked for me to print the font after `HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile()`.

Uschi